# C# Array returning a value that's not in it

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I'm learning C# and following some simple guides. I'm having an issue and don't understand what's happening. Is it my Visual Studio breaking?

I have:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Learning_C_Sharp
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int[] myNumbers = { 10, 20, 30, 40, 50 };
            for (int i = 0; i < myNumbers.Length; i++)
                Console.WriteLine(myNumbers[i]);
            //Console.WriteLine(myNumbers[0]);
            Console.Read();
        }
    }
}
```

I should get a result of 10, 20, 30, 40, 50. However I'm getting 224 as my first number returned instead of 10, regardless of what I set the first number to.

Is my Visual Studio just broken?

I've since uninstalled and reinstalled with no change. Created a new project and manually typed the code in with no change. So long as the array is int,  the first value is being returned as 224. Also it accepts math, if I say to return the value and add one, then I get 225.

Screenshot to show debug too.

[image: Screenshot of VS showing debug]

Additional Edits:

[I've stripped this down to bare bones and regardless of how I do it, I still get the same results.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cbObA.png)

I've uninstalled, reinstalled, used Revo Uninstaller to completely obliterate VS. Tuesday I'm going to reimage my computer unless someone has an idea.

Comment: Use the debugger to step through the code, and see what it shows when you mouse over `myNumbers[i]` when the debugger is stopped on that line.

Comment: Issue is not reproducible with code which you have posted https://dotnetfiddle.net/2kob2w

Comment: Are you sure you're not running a different project? Your code works correctly for me.

Comment: No, your VS installation is not broken (probably). You just got confused somewhere, somehow. Screenshot of VS running your code together with where exactly you see the 224 pop up could perhaps help...

Comment: It works for me in Visual Studio.

Comment: Added a screenshot to show the debug confirming the error. It's gotta be my VS installation right? Unless someone has a better idea I'm about to uninstall reinstall to see if that clears things up.

Comment: It sounds _extremely_ unlikely that a corrupted VS installation would produce this specific error. Your code wouldn't run at all. Have you tried cleaning and rebuilding the project?

Comment: Created a whole new project and manually typed in the exact same code, get the exact same response. I'm uninstalling and reinstall VS. I'll report back after that. Fingers crossed.

Comment: Uninstalled and reinstalled VS and no change....My screenshot shows everything, what is going on? I'm hesitant to continue the tutorials until I can be sure that any issues that occur are a result of me and not a bad IDE.

Comment: Let me know if you ever figure this one out. I'm genuinely stumped.

Comment: Can this be taken off Hold? I've added extra screenshots confirming it's an issue and added additional troubleshooting steps I've done.

Comment: @gilliduck I voted to reopen as well - it's reopen now

Comment: I don't think we can help with issue that can't be reproduced. You can try changing the project .NET version or a different type of project just in case.

Comment: Check your computer's regional settings.

Comment: Some general debugging questions. What version of visual studio and what update version, what's the framework version, what are your PC's regional settings

Comment: If you are learning C# please follow the recommended guidelines for code style and place braces around all code blocks (`if()` and `for()` statements). It is very easy to make a mistake if you are relying on indentation to indicate code blocks _because C# isn't Python_

Comment: I can't seem to get a reply through without it being deemed irrelevant.  I had the exact same issue until I updated to Visual Studio Update 3 and then restarted my machine.  I was getting 0xE0 (224 decimal) in the first index of my array as well.  Before applying the updates I could check "Enable the Visual Studio Hosting Process" under Project->Debug and that would fix my issue.  If that was unchecked the problem cam back.

Comment: Are you using release or debug builds?  Do you have anything in the watch list?  Does the problem only happen when debugging?  Have you tried a different variable name?

Comment: I can't comment on the actual solution, but it does appear to be a quirk isolated to VS Community 2017. I'm now on Pro 2017 and the exact same code does not reproduce the error. I'm going to chalk this up to a Microsoft bug.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't comment on the actual solution, but it does appear to be a quirk isolated to VS Community 2017. I'm now on Pro 2017 and the exact same code does not reproduce the error. I'm going to chalk this up to a Microsoft bug. There does appear to be workarounds available, however the core issue itself appears for all intents to be a glitch specific to that version of VS. Unless anyone else can provide better info on it, I say call this closed due to Microsoft glitch.

Comment: What happens if you simply print the values to the console, do you get the incorrect value then? Because if not it is simply the debugger acting up.